# Why does my countdown timer jump 20 minutes after 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, time

I have a weird bug in my setInterval / timer() function code.

I have a countdown timer for 20 minutes (and 0 seconds), and it should count down every second, but it's counting down weirdly. (See CSVs below)

I tried surrounding parseInts for the minutes and seconds, but it just makes the `Time Displayed`'s outputs become NaN**

```js
var n = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  var time = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
  var minutes = time[1] + time[2];
  var seconds = time[12] + time[13];
  if (seconds == 0) {
    minutes--;
    seconds = 59;
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = (minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds');
}
```

```html
<button id = 'timer'>
30 minutes 00 seconds</button>
```

As you can see, the code jumps the time weirdly. 
(CSVs here*)

```
    Time Displayed            min sec
    30 minutes 00 seconds,     29,59,
    29 minutes 59 seconds,     9 ,8,
    9  minutes 8 seconds,        ,NaN,
       minutes NaN seconds,      ,NaN,
       minutes NaN seconds,      ,NaN,
       minutes NaN seconds,      ,NaN,
    etc
```

I suspect it's something to do with the if statement somehow deleting minutes[0] and seconds[0] with the decrements, but I can't figure out why.

**Why does this happen? How do I fix it?**

<sub>*: I got these from outputting [document.getElementById('timer').value, minutes, seconds] to a separate textarea when the else statement was done, just before I updated the timer value. I also separated the `Time Displayed` from the `minutes` and `seconds` for you.</sub>

<sub>**: I mean after the `9 minutes 8 seconds` there's `NaN minutes NaN seconds.` It doesn't become NaN immediately.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is how you are taking the characters from the string `time`

```
For the string: "30 minutes 00 seconds"
time[1] = 0
time[2] = " "
```

It gives `NaN` when `time[1]` or `time[2]` happens to be the empty string. 
In that case the operation `--` over a string gives `NaN`.

**I would rely on splitting the phrase into tokens, rather than getting single characters.**
 Try:

```js
var n = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  var time = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML.split(" "); //splits the string "30 minutes 00 seconds" in an array with 4 elements.
  var minutes = time[0];
  var seconds = time[2];
  if (seconds == 0) {
 minutes--;
 seconds = 59;
  } else {
 seconds--;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = (minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds');
}
```

```html
<button id='timer'>30 minutes 00 seconds</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Becaues you're overwriting the variables with every function call, put the variables outside the function :

```js
var n = setInterval(timer, 1000);

var time = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
var minutes = time[1] + time[2];
var seconds = time[12] + time[13];

function timer() {
  if (seconds == 0) {
    minutes--;
    seconds = 59;
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }

  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = (minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds');
}
```

```html
<button id='timer'>
30 minutes 00 seconds</button>
```

Comment: And make the delay just a little less than 1000 because depending on how much of a partial second you are at when you need to display the seconds, you could wind up skipping one. I usually use 900 milliseconds.